# Deriving the "total" Bose Einstein density of states, including the condensate

Tags: statistical-mechanics, bose-einstein-condensate

Is is possible to derive the Bose-Einstein density of states containing the delta function representing the BE condensate?

Comment: What do you mean by "total density of states"? The basic DoS is a single particle quantity and just depends the dispersion relation, so it doesn't care about BEC or anything.

Comment: @BebopButUnsteady: My bad! I should have said B-E distribution function. What I wanted to know is there a purely mathematical derivation of the delta function which corresponds to the BEC. In all the "derivations" I have seen so far, it is put by hand.